# ansible 1.9 : win_package module is missing

Tags: ansible

trying to install some softwares from ubuntu-14.0.4 LTS control box to "Windows 2k12 R2" using

```
- name: installing required softwares
  win_package:
     name: "Notepad++"
     path: "https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/6.x/6.8.7/npp.6.8.7.Installer.exe"
     state: present
```

but on execution i am getting:

```
ERROR: win_package is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
```

after some research i found said module is missing in ansible1.9 default packages but available in some git repo : "https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/devel/windows/win_package.py"

downloaded it to "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/core/windows"

again tried running but no success so far ,....
and it returned

```
fatal: [192.168.9.115] => module is missing interpreter line -win_package
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you completely followed the [installation instructions](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html) posted on the ansible website?  How exactly did you install ansible?

Comment: yes, used pip install and followed instructions completely posted there.

Answer (score 1):

The module you're looking for is part of the upcoming 2.0 release of Ansible, see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/CHANGELOG.md.

I'm not sure if you can use 2.0 modules in older versions of Ansible, so I would recommend to get the new version. But be careful, it's still a release candidate.

You can install Ansible 2.0 like this:

```
pip install http://releases.ansible.com/ansible/ansible-2.0.0-0.6.rc1.tar.gz
```

You find all releases at http://releases.ansible.com/ansible/.